# Reuse the linq table class when selecting from view

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have an sql server table linked to class via the linq attribute:

```
[Table(Name = "MyItems")]
public class MyItems
{
    ...
}

Table<MyItems> linqMyItems = db.GetTable<MyItems>();
IQueryable<MyItems> itmList = (
    from itm in linqMyItems
    select itm);
```

This works fine when I need to query on this table and update its items. But now I'd like to reuse this class, when I select the data from a database view `ItemsFiltered` that contains exactly the same set of fields. Basically I am ok with just read-only object, but if the linq would magically connect the field set retrieved from view to the actual related table, thus making the object update-able, I wouldn't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Just use heredety

```
public abstract class MyItemsBase
{
    /* Define everything here */
}

[Table(Name = "MyItems")]
public class TableMyItems : MyItemsBase { }

[Table(Name = "ItemsFiltered")]
public class ViewMyItems : MyItemsBase { }
```

Comment: I get error, not sure how to fix it: InvalidOperationException: Data member 'Int32 itmID' of type 'UserQuery+MyItemsBase' is not part of the mapping for type 'ItemsFiltered'. Is the member above the root of an inheritance hierarchy?